# Postgresql Disk Allocation in Begin End Transaction

Tags: postgresql, transaction

I have a loop in transaction block that creates a temporary table,updates,exports to txt file and drops table at the end of the block.
After some time I noticed that disk size was getting smaller each time loop continued.When I cancelled transaction block,disk size returned to its initial state.

How can I stop loop for allocating the disk on the following transaction ?

```
do
$$declare
  --variables
begin
     FOR r IN (SELECT ...) LOOP
        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TEST .. ;
        --UPDATE STATEMENTS
        --EXPORT (COPIES TABLE INTO TXT FILE)
        DROP TABLE TEST CASCADE;
     END LOOP;
end$$;
```

Comment: Additionally: why are you creating the same table over and over again? Why don't you create it **once** _before_ the loop? And why do you think you need a temporary table in the first place? What exactly does the "export" part do?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name What if I create table in the first place,then insert and truncate on loop,would statement still allocate disk ? On export part,there is a copy statement to write the table into a txt file,that's all.

Comment: It would expect it allocate the space only once and overwrite it in each iteration. But as I hardly ever use temp tables, I am not surel. Why don't you use the `select` statement that builds the temp table directly in the `copy` statement? Or use a temporary _view_ instead?

Comment: I forgot to mention that before exporting table,there are lots of update statements.I can't select it directly because of the updates.

Answer (score 1):

Any space allocated for temporary tables will not be released until the transaction is committed (when using `on commit delete rows`) or even later when the connection is closed (`on commit preserve rows`, which is the default). - https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1822